# is the search component of mongodb update also atomic?

Tags: mongodb, atomic

From the [MongoDB Update documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating) they talk about the update operators being atomic.  If the below query is called five times at the same instant and Zugwalt's reputation starts at zero, I'd expect at the end for the reputation to be 5:

```
db.rep.update({_id: "Zugwalt"}, {$inc: {reputation: 1}});
```

However what if the update query is this?

```
db.rep.update({_id: "Zugwalt", reputation: {$lte: 3}}, {$inc: {reputation: 1}});
```

Would the reputation always only be updated three times or is there some weird race conditions where it could be more?

My particular case is using an active user to "claim a document".  I execute a query similar to:

```
db.myCollection.update({_id: "doc_id", activeUser: {$exists: false}}, {$set: {activeUser: "Zugwalt"}});
```

Ideally if this query fires multiple times at the same instance only one update will result in the collection being modified.  However If the search component isn't atomic with the update I could see a race condition where its first updated to set the activeUser to one user, and then immediately to another.

Side note: it seems more clear that the [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) command has this kind of atomicness, however I don't want to use it as in our empirical testing with our node-js driver it seems much slower overall under heavy load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MongoDB updates are atomic.  If you don't need to get the document back, you don't need to use findAndModify.

In the scenarios you give, the expected thing will happen - in the first case reputation will end up as 5, in the second it'll be 4.

In your case only one update will successfully set activeUser.

Here is a [link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+operation+examples) that discusses atomic operations in MongoDB.

Comment: now if you needed to get back the document you modified then you would want to use findAndModify.

Comment: Hey Asya, how do you know this?  Is there a link you could provide?  Also in our experience we found using update, followed by a find to be much faster than findAndModify!  Perhaps because we use nodejs which has a single event loop so its good to be able to other things get a chance to execute in between the update and find.

Comment: I'll add the link to the answer - it's example number 2 here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+operation+examples

Answer (score 0):

For such scenarios you should use [`findAndModify`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command). It's fully atomic.

Something like this:

```
db.runCommand({findAndModify: 'myCollection',
               query: {_id: "doc_id", activeUser: {$exists: false}},
               update: {$set: {activeUser: "Zugwalt"}}})
```

Comment: As I pointed out in my side note I realize findAndModify is, however I was wondering if update is full atomic as well as we don't need the modified object.

Comment: What if you compare it to updates in safe mode? Is the speed comparable (the same)?

Comment: we do the updates in safe mode, and they are still much faster than findAndModify (which makes me question if its is atomic or not)